# Psycopg2 string formatting with variable names for type creation

Tags: python, postgresql, list-comprehension, psycopg2

When passing in a variable type name for creation in postgres using psycopg2 using its formatting option, an error was throw over bad string formatting for the name of objects. Are names not allowed to be passed in using %s within the query parameters?

The code I wrote that does solve my issues is below (just looking for a better way to resolve this)

```
cursor.execute("CREATE TYPE {0} AS ENUM %s".format(name), (tuple(set([e.upper() for e in elements])),))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you guessed, you can't pass things like table names as query parameters.

They're sent as protocol level bind parameters and (critically) the query *must be parseable as valid SQL with them as placeholders*. It's as if you were to run an SQL-level `PREPARE` then separate `EXECUTE`. You must format them into the SQL string before preparing it, using appropriate identifier quoting.

Double quote the identifier(s) you're substituting in and beware of possible double quotes within the string you're being passed that might prematurely end your quoted sequence. These must be doubled. For example, for the table name `some"table` you would use:

```
 'SELECT * FROM "{0}"'.format('some""table');
```

SQL injection is a very serious risk; you must get your quoting *exactly* right. Ideally find a client-side equivalent of the PostgreSQL `quote_ident` SQL function.

Note that double quoted identifiers are case sensitive. Make sure you create them with the same case in the DB by always using them double quoted, don't mix quoted and unquoted identifiers.

Answer (score 2):

You should actually never python-format your queries, but let *psycopg2* do it. Here is the way to make it: http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries i.e:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO numbers VALUES (%s)", (42,))
```

Starting with the 2.7 version, some advanced formatting possibilities are available through the `psycopg2.sql` module: http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/sql.html

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem also and wrote a short [blog post](http://josephfusaro.com/string-formatting-errors-psycopg/) which covers the connection to a remote database using string formatting but this issue and my resolution is applicable to any situation where you need to pass variables to SQL commands.

Here is how I worked around this issue:

```
import psycopg2 as db
import sys

my_host = 'ec2-190-111-829-829.compute-1.amazonaws.com'
my_dbname = 'myDBNameGoesHere'
my_user = 'myUsernameGoesHere'
my_password = 'myPasswordGoesHere'
remote_connection_str = 'host={0} dbname={1} user={2} password={3}'.format(my_host, my_dbname, my_user, my_password)

if __name__ == '__main__':
     try:
          remote_connection = db.connect(remote_connection_str)
          cursor = remote_connection.cursor()
          cursor.execute('SELECT version()')
          version = cursor.fetchone()
          print "\n"
          print "Successful connection to database."
          print "Database information:\n", version
          print "\n"

     except db.DatabaseError, e:
          print 'Error %s' % e
          sys.exit(1)

     finally:
          if remote_connection:
          remote_connection.close()
```