# Insert a single variable into a table in PostgreSQL using python

Tags: postgresql, python-3.x, psycopg2

I am trying to insert a single value into a Postgres table with two columns. The first column is an auto-increasing primary key while the second column should be a variable. I have done some research and found the following resources [TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18053500/typeerror-not-all-arguments-converted-during-string-formatting-python), [How to set auto increment primary key in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718585/how-to-set-auto-increment-primary-key-in-postgresql,and) this [Psycopg2 string formatting with variable names for type creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12771209/psycopg2-string-formatting-with-variable-names-for-type-creation).

```
import psycopg2

try:
    conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=postgres user=postgres password=actuarial")
    print("database created successfully.")
except psycopg2.OperationalError as ex:
    print("Connection failed: {0}".format(ex))
cur = conn.cursor()

def create_client_table():
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE ClientTable (ClientID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, Name varchar);")
    print('student table created successfully')

create_client_table()

def client_add():
    name = input("Enter the names of the student:")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO CleintTable VALUES (%s)", (name));
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM StudentTable")
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    print(rows)
client_add()

conn.close()
```

Upon running the code above I get the following error. Kindly help me identify where I am going wrong.

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO CleintTable VALUES (%s)", (name));

TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A comma is necessary after `name` to turn that parenthesized expression into a tuple:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO CleintTable VALUES (%s)", (name,));
```

Otherwise it is a string sequence over which the `execute` method will iterate.

Answer (score 0):

"CleintTable" might need to be changed to ClientTable, unless you intentionally named the table this way. Just something I noticed when reading your code, apart from what you were looking for.